# Extension method (like Take()) not available for the LINQ query, Any reason why?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I want to retrieve only top 100 items from the `DataTable` object. I have done this before on the generic lists using `Take()` method, but not sure why it's not available for this one.

Below is my `LINQ` query:

```
    IEnumerable<DataRow> query = (from task in dtTasks.AsEnumerable()
                                  where  task.Field<DateTime>("EstimatedStartTimeStamp") <= DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Today.Date.AddDays(1).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"))
                                 orderby task.Field<DateTime>("Status")
                                 select task);

    DataTable boundTable = query.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
```

The problem is when I try to use Take() method, it just doesn`t show up in the intellisense. It shows other methods like OrderBy/OrderByDescending.

---

***UPDATE***: dtTasks is a `DataTable` object.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: What happens if you write `Enumerable.Take(query, 2)`?

Comment: Where are you trying to call `Take()`?

Comment: Where are you attempting to call `Take()` from?  It should be `query.Take(100)...` or `(from ....).Take(100)...`

Comment: At the end of bracket, like this query = (from......select task).Take(100);

Comment: Would you happen to have `using System.Linq;` in your file? You can write a perfectly good query expression syntax statement without it, but the explicit use of the *extension methods* will want it.

Comment: Of course, stupid me. I don't know why is it even allowed to write full LINQ query without even having to include System.LINQ library. I wrote almost 10 functions with LINQ query and with successful results. But never had a reference to System.Linq ....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that you have the assembly below in Reference of both your WebUI and Domain (Depending on how you have your system set up).

```
Assembly:  System.Core (in System.Core.dll)
```

Then have this Namespace in your controller where `Take` method is being called.

```
Namespace:  System.Linq
```

Comment: Yes, System.Linq is what I was missing. But as I wrote all my function using LINQ query with correct results, I never looked for System.Linq which my guess is required for extension methods.

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure you have added the reference to assembly `System.Data.DataSetExtensions` and have the following using directives:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Data.Linq;
```

It has to be noted that `List<T>.AsEnumerable` is part of assembly `System.Core` and namespace:

using System.Linq;

while, `DataTable.AsEnumerable` is part of assembly: `System.Data.DataSetExtensions` and namespace:

```
using System.Data;
```

and, in any case

`.Take<int32>` is part of namespace:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: I have already imported System.Data. Why do I need to import System.Data.Linq?

Comment: Close. But it's not the System.Data.Linq library it's the System.Linq that I was missing.

Comment: ok. I can see now in your code, that you already have converted `DataTable` to `AsEnumerable` which comes from `DataSetExtensions assembly`, but I was not sure..

Answer (score 1):

```
var query = (from task in dtTasks.AsEnumerable()
             where  task.Field<DateTime>("EstimatedStartTimeStamp") <= DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Today.Date.AddDays(1).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"))
             orderby task.Field<DateTime>("Status")
             select task).Take(3);
```

Doesn't compile for you?

Do you have a reference to `System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll`?

If I create a new windows forms project and add `using System.Data;` to the top of the class, the following compiles just fine:

```
var dt = new DataTable();

var query = (from t in dt.AsEnumerable()
             select t).Take(1);
```

Perhaps clean/rebuild would fix it for you?

Comment: Doesn't compile. Error: 'System.Data.OrderedEnumerableRowCollection<System.Data.DataRow>' does not contain a definition for 'Take' and no extension method 'Take' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.OrderedEnumerableRowCollection<System.Data.DataRow>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?). And, yes, I have that dll referenced.

Comment: Works for me in the venerable LINQPad.

Comment: Ahhh! that's where the problem is. When I try to use the library, I get this Error: The type or namespace name 'DataSetExtensions' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data' (are you missing an assembly reference?).

Comment: @Learner you actually don't need the full reference, just `using System.Data;` will suffice.

Comment: Yeah, in that case Take() does not appear at all.

Comment: Maybe something goofy like targeting the wrong framework in project properties?

Comment: Yes, looks like I am definitely doing something foolish or missing something. I will try creating a small test project and see what happens. +1 for your help and time.

Comment: Stupid me. I don't know why is it even allowed to write full LINQ query without even having to include System.LINQ library. I wrote almost 10 functions with LINQ query and with successful results. But never had a reference to System.Linq. My guess is Linq Query required System.Data.Linq while extension methods need System.Linq. Thanks again!

Comment: @Learner: No.  LINQ queries use any available method; they don't care what namespace it comes from.  You've been using `DataTable`-specific extensions in `System.Data` in `System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll`, which do not include `Take()`.

Comment: @SLaks `.Take()` becomes available by casting the `dataTable.AsEnumerable()`, no?

Comment: @TomStudee: Yes, but only if `System.LINQ` is imported.  (Unlike `Select()` and `Where()`, which he's using from `System.Data` after `AsEnumerable()`)

Comment: Ahh, ok, now I understand.